# Stack driver adapter installation on istio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, adapter, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

We have installed Istio manually on GKE cluster. We want to install/add istio stack driver adapter so that Istio metrics are available on Stack Driver monitoring Dashboard of GCP. I am not able to get the metrics despite add the CRD as mentioned in

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/istio-samples/blob/master/common/install_istio.sh

```
git clone https://github.com/istio/installer && cd installer
helm template istio-telemetry/mixer-telemetry --execute=templates/stackdriver.yaml -f global.yaml --set mixer.adapters.stackdriver.enabled=true --namespace istio-system | kubectl apply -f -
```

I feel we are missing the authentication part. Can anyone help in resolving this?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate your set up and I notice that the Istio version downloaded by the script was 1.4.2 which is not [supported by GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/versions) at this moment.
Nonetheless, I’d recommend you to check [this](https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/installation/telemetry-troubleshooting?hl=en) document for troubleshooting and consult [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#creating_a_cluster_with_istio_on_gke) to get Istio installed on GKE.

You should also be aware of couple of limitations when using [Istio on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/overview#should_i_use_istio_on_gke)

Comment: this https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/installation/telemetry-troubleshooting?hl=en link is broken